# Animated slides conversion into static PDF

Tags: pdf, animation

For all of you, people who make ppt slides with animations like:

- Showing bullet points one by one
- Showing images one by one or zooming a plot
- Showing a border on an active element
- Internal navigation / menu / link to another slide
- Transitions between slides

Is there a tool that can convert the ppt to PDF and keep each animation in a separate slide, for example?

I know you can create animated slides with **LaTeX Beamer** that convert nicely to PDF, I have made some of those, but I also have some ppt files that I want to convert to PDF.

This is what I have tried so far:

- **[Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/)**, however not only it doesn't support animations, but internal navigation doesn't work, and the fonts are all messed up.
- **[PDFcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)**, the quality is quite superior in comparison, but it doesn't support the animations neither. As Slideshare, it will just put one image over the other. Also, it doesn't support transparency (for example, a text box with a semitransparent bg over an image)
- **LaTeX Beamer**, already mentioned, but I would prefer to avoid typing these ppts content and animations into LaTeX just so that the animations are displayed correctly in PDF.

I have searched SO and didn't find a satisfactory answer to deal with animations. What do you use?

Cheers!